# Acting on a tensor product of vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

If I have an algebra $A$ acting on vector spaces $U$ and $V$ and an element $\alpha\in A\otimes A$, is there a canonical way I can let $\alpha$ act on $U\otimes V$?

Comment: Yes, you can define the action on pure tensors: $a \otimes b \cdot v \otimes w = (a \cdot v) \otimes (b \cdot w)$, then extend linearly.
Though to clarify, what are you considering $U \otimes V$ to be tensored over, the ground field or $A$?  If $A$, then this won't work.

Comment: The ground field. Thank you!

Comment: @Jonathan you should post your comment as an answer.